# BGA VCC and VSS shorted after desoldering

Tags: soldering, short-circuit, reflow, bga, rework

I am really confused with working with BGA chips.

I am new to this but have been following other guides so I thought I should give it a try. I am using a DIY pre heater that has a 800watt IR bottom heater and for the top heater I am using a hot air station with 40x40mm nozzle that's about the size of the BGA chip I am trying to rework.

[image]

I am desoldering an Intel JG82855GME chipset chip. I left the board on the preheater and set it to 100°C for 9-10 hours to remove any moisture. Afterwards I removed the BGA  by setting my preheater at 220°C and hot air station at 350-380°C.

It's interesting to note that even though the bottom preheater is set to 220°C, the PCB only reaches about 120-130°C.

Why is that so?

The PCB is about 10x10cm in size while the heater is 12x12cm so the whole PCB is covered completely by the heater.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After I removed the BGA chip I probed its VCC and VSS pins and found a short on those pins. Is the chip dead, or is there still some hope left for it? Is the hot air station a bad choice for this task?

Comment: What was your measurement method for finding the short? How much voltage or current did you apply, and what current or voltage limit did you use to decide there was a short?

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand people at all.  A photo, Ok.  A screenshot of a photo, WTF?

Comment: @ThePhoton I didn't apply any power to check the short. I used continuity mode on my multimeter to test it. It's giving about 0.2ohms reading which it also gives when I touch the two probes together.

Comment: @JRE I couldn't upload the picture as the image size was greater than 2mb and I was on mobile so just took screenshots of my image to reduce file size. Sorry about that :P

Comment: @speedstr, How do you think continuity mode on your meter works?

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh you were referring to that yeah i applied some "power" in that case :p but i suppose thats too weak and shouldn't damage the chip. I have a UNI-T UT139c which i used to measure resistance of the chip. Not sure about its current and voltage limit in continuity mode

Comment: The question isn't whether you damaged the chip. It's whether the chip draws enough current, even with a low applied voltage to fool your meter into thinking it's a short. A chip with that many pads probably draws a fair amount of current (several A, at least) so your meter might consider it a "short" even if it's working normally.

Comment: It's also possible there are some discrete components inside the chip package, and your re-work process has desoldered them and caused a short.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh i see, that makes perfect sense. I just checked the data sheet and under the electrical characteristics it says the core voltage is about 1.3 volts and TDP of around 4 watts. Any idea how to test it before I reinstall it in the board ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy to test. Regarding the continuity check mode of your multimeter, that has an output voltage of 1V or greater so that it can test a diode or light up an LED. Older chips that run on 5V or so may have high enough thresholds that they do not "turn on" and consume any current when you do the continuity check on their power pins, but new chips have an operating voltage around the same as it takes to turn a diode on, so they look like a short or diode.

Comment: I see, do you guys suggest a test with lab bench powersupply ? Ill set the voltage to about the nominal Vcore voltage listed in the datasheet and see how much amps the chip is drawing at that voltage. The specs suggest around Ivcc max 2.25A @1.35 Vcore

Comment: But that would be quite difficult and will take a long time to solder all those VCC and VSS pins

Comment: This chip is dead as i was lucky enough to find another board which had an identical chip. The measured resistance accross that chip is about 216.5 Ohms so i think there's definitely some problem with this one as its resistance should've been atleast greater than 216.5 ohms

Comment: Good question, and your setup is pretty nice! You have a lot of initiative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your 2 questions :

1. **Question 1** - Is the chip dead, or is there still some hope left for it?
   ***Answer*** - *Hard to say if device was damaged due to the rework process or it was 
   not-functioning even before*
2. **Question 2** - Is the hot air station a bad choice for this task?
   ***Answer*** - No, the hot air station is OK, but at any rate...

...you *should* "mask" the card bottom side, in such a way the bottom heater heats up 
   only the area where the BGA is located (preserving other components nearby); however, 120-130°C is a temperature good enough for the card bottom side

...as per the top side of the board, you *should* thermally protect/isolate components nearby the BGA device to rework

EDIT : BGA rework implies 2 thermal stresses, and you certainly know how much the thermal stresses are important. Just for this reason, one of the principles on reworking of massive components (specially on massive boards), is to depopulate the host board as much as possible, before going to desoldering and to soldering a new component on it. 
Also, you have to consider that is if you want to recovery the board functionality due to a damaged component by reworking it, you must keep in mind not to damage or thermally stressing the other components on the board. So, in principle, the rework process should be conducted in a way to stress the host board as less as you can.

Comment: I appreciate and agree with the points you laid down but I have a question relating to the mask you said for the bottom heater. Wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of that bottom preheater ? Like what I've been following is that its used to make all the parts of the pcb reach an equilibrium temperature and saturate the thermal mass (Heat sinks and Copper planes) so that once the top heater is turned on, Its heat wouldn't be sinked to nearby elements.

Comment: See my added considerations in the edited answer.